# Deduce $\tau _k (p^e) = {{e+k-1}\choose{k-2}}.$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\tau_k(n)$ be the number of ordered factorizations of $n$ as the product of exactly $k$ positive integers so that $\tau _1(n)=1$ and $\tau _2(n) = \tau (n)$. For fixed $k$, show $\tau _k (p^e) < (e+1)^k$ to deduce 
>   $$\tau _k (p^e) = {{e+k-1}\choose{k-2}}.$$

First, I feel that the deduction to be made is $$\tau _k (p^e) = {{e+k-1}\choose{k-1}},$$ not $$\tau _k (p^e) = {{e+k-1}\choose{k-2}},$$ is this true? If not, why would what I suggested not hold? Also, it follows that $\tau_k (n)$ is multiplicative, which allows us to consider the case of prime powers, but I am not sure how the rest of the proof would follow from this. I showed that $\tau (n) \ll n^{\delta}$ for any $\delta >0$. The proof of this follows by considering $$f(n) = \frac{\tau (n)}{n^{\delta}}$$ and noting $f$ is multiplicative, but I am not sure if this helps much with the results we want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your objection is valid.

If $p$ is prime, and $e$ is a nonnegative integer, an ordered factorization of $p^e$ into $k$ positive integer factors has the form
$$(p^{x_1})\cdots(p^{x_k})$$
where $x_1,...,x_k$ are nonnegative integers such that
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_k = e$$
hence, by the stars-and-bars formula, it follows that
$$\tau _k (p^e) = {{e+k-1}\choose{k-1}}$$

Comment: I have not seen the "stars-and-bars" formula until now. Are you referring to Theorem 2 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) ? If so, could you clarify how you concluded the last result? I think you first considered ${{e+k-1}\choose{e}}$ and used the formula to obtain ${{e+k-1}\choose{k-1}},$ is this true?

Comment: It's a standard formula. The formula I've seen in books states that the number of nonnegative integer solutions $(x_1....,x_n)$ to the equation $$x_1 + \cdots + x_n=r$$
is given by
$$\binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$$
Of course, that's algebraically equivalent to
$$\binom{r+n-1}{r}$$
In the context of this problem, I used the first of the above formulas, with $n=k$, and $r=e$.